# Get the errors in Application_Start() with NLog and redirect to friendly page error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, nlog

I need to catch any error in the Application_Start() and redirect to an HTML error page but NLog is not logging anything if I have an error, for example, the database unavailable:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

protected void Application_Start()
{
    try
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutofacConfig.RegisterDependencies();
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        SimpleMemberShipConfig.SimpleMembershipInitializer();
        EntityFrameworkConfig.Configure();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error(e);
    }
}
```

NLog configuration:

```
<targets>

     <target xsi:type="File" name="Heelp_log" fileName="${basedir}/logs/Heelp-${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true} ${message}" />

</targets>
<rules>

     <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="Heelp_log" />

</rules>
```

To redirect I have:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.html" />
```

But it goes to a page like this (/Views/Shared/Error.html?aspxerrorpath=/):

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in the Gloabal.Ascx

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "General";            
        routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            switch (Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                    break;
            }
        }

        IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
```

And add a ErrorController

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult General()
    {            
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }

    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Http403()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Add your respective views to the same

Hope it may help you. Thankyou and have a nice day.

Comment: Hi, thanks! How do you suggest that I log the error using NLog?